# Convert C# string to win-1251

Tags: c#, string, encode, windows-1251

I have the following string:

```
string str = "Здравей!";
```

I have to pass it to a printer to print it. The printer method to print is `datecs_test.PrintTaggedText(str);` But on print I don't get the same string content but some strange symbols. They told me that before I pass `str` to `datecs_test.PrintTaggedText(str);` I have to convert `str` to `win-1251`. But all solutions I find doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You try obtaining bytes `byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(str);` which then pass to `datecs_test`

Comment: If `PrintTaggedText` accepts a `string` but expects it to be anything other than UTF-16, then it is not a good method and it must be fixed, because `string` means "a sequence of UTF-16 chars". If `PrintTaggedText` accepts a `byte[]`, then I find it difficult to believe that you even looked for solutions.

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko but the method `datecs_test.PrintTaggedText(str)` expects a string

Comment: Whenever you work with a `string` in C# it will always be a sequence of [UTF-16 chars](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char) -- as shown, you can get a `byte[]` *representation* of it in a different encoding, but a `string` will always be a `string` (and always in UTF-16).

Comment: @ProfileForStack4 In that case what you are being told to do doesn't make much sense. A `string` cannot represent a `win-1251` value; it can only be converted into bytes representing a `win-1251` value. Do you have any documentation on this library?

Comment: I don't understand, so how do I convert the string to `win1251` so I can pas it to the method.

Comment: You don't. If you have a method signature on the C# side that accepts a `string`, it has to be a normal .NET UTF-16 string. If the printer does not understand that, then the code inside `PrintTaggedText` should manage the conversion. Obligatory reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: the printer has a method which accepts `byte[]` I saw it now `datecs_test.PrintText(data);` . Thanks!

Comment: Printers like that (thermal printers that use ESC codes) in general have their own device fonts.  You have to send anther command to switch the character set.  Look in the programming manual for the command, ensure it actually has a font that can display Cyrillic glyphs.